# vba target intersect with comments added - object error msg

Tags: vba, debugging, event-handling, target

I have the following piece of code which works really well given what I used it for. In debugging possible outcomes, I found that for example if I try to change the TARGET range by either ADDING or DELETING A ROW , I get a VBA Error:

If I add a row in target-> i get "Object Required" - #424
If I delete a row in target -> I get "Method Undo of Object Application Failed" - #1001 (I know this is due to the fact I am using UNDO to get the old cell value, but don't know how to resolve)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

Dim newvalue As Variant
Dim oldvalue As Variant
Dim cell As Range
Dim trg As String

' to replace current comment with new one

'If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
'MsgBox "new value " & newvalue & vbLf & "old value " & oldvalue
'    If ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
'    ActiveCell.AddComment ("Old Value: " & oldvalue & vbNewLine & "New Value: " & newvalue)
'    Else
'    ActiveCell.Comment.Delete
'    ActiveCell.AddComment ("Old Value: " & oldvalue & vbNewLine & "New Value: " & newvalue)
'    End If

'to append comments to existing comment

On Error GoTo ermess

If Not Application.Intersect(target, Range("A1", "A10")) Is Nothing Then

     For Each cell In target

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        newvalue = cell.Value
        Application.Undo
        oldvalue = cell.Value
        cell.Value = newvalue
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 19

                    If newvalue <> oldvalue Then

                       ' If (Target.Address = "$A$1") Then
                        MsgBox "new value " & newvalue & vbLf & "old value " & oldvalue

                            If cell.Comment Is Nothing Then
                            cell.AddComment ("Old Value: " & oldvalue & vbNewLine & "New Value: " & newvalue & vbNewLine & "Updated: " & Now & vbNewLine & "By: " & Environ("username"))
                            Else
                            With target
                            .Comment.Text Text:=.Comment.Text & vbNewLine & ("Old Value: " & oldvalue & vbNewLine & "New Value: " & newvalue & vbNewLine & "Updated: " & Now _
                            & vbNewLine & "By: " & Environ("username"))
                            End With

                            End If

                        'End If

                    Else
0
                    End If
                    'Set target = Nothing

      Next cell
Else

'to test if not in the target specified
'MsgBox "Not in range"

End If

'Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub
ermess:
MsgBox "VBA Error" & vbLf & Err.Description & vbLf & Err.Number, vbCritical

'Debug.Print
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

What I want to do it to reset the range so that the "object required" message is eliminated if possible.

With regards to the "application undo" message -> I know that using this to retrieve a previous value of a cell is not the best method, but it worked for me , so if there is a solution to this tthat would be desired.

I don't want to use "On error resume next" as I want to clean up the code first.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. For anyone interested I added an if statement which evaluated the target range count (if > 1 then exit the sub)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

Dim newvalue As Variant
Dim oldvalue As Variant
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim trg As String

' to replace current comment with new one

'If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
'MsgBox "new value " & newvalue & vbLf & "old value " & oldvalue
'    If ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
'    ActiveCell.AddComment ("Old Value: " & oldvalue & vbNewLine & "New Value: " & newvalue)
'    Else
'    ActiveCell.Comment.Delete
'    ActiveCell.AddComment ("Old Value: " & oldvalue & vbNewLine & "New Value: " & newvalue)
'    End If

'to append comments to existing comment

Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A11")

On Error GoTo ermess

    **If target.Count <= 1 Then 'Exit Sub**

        If Not Application.Intersect(target, rng2) Is Nothing Then

             For Each cell In target

           ' On Error Resume Next
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            newvalue = cell.Value
            Application.Undo
            oldvalue = cell.Value
            cell.Value = newvalue
            'On Error GoTo ExitProc
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 19

           '         If newvalue <> Empty Then

                        If newvalue <> oldvalue Then

                           ' If (Target.Address = "$A$1") Then
                            MsgBox "new value " & newvalue & vbLf & "old value " & oldvalue

                                If cell.Comment Is Nothing Then
                                cell.AddComment ("Old Value: " & oldvalue & vbNewLine & "New Value: " & newvalue & vbNewLine & "Updated: " & Now & vbNewLine & "By: " & Environ("username"))
                                Else
                                With target
                                .Comment.Text Text:=.Comment.Text & vbNewLine & ("Old Value: " & oldvalue & vbNewLine & "New Value: " & newvalue & vbNewLine & "Updated: " & Now _
                                & vbNewLine & "By: " & Environ("username"))
                                End With

                                End If

                            'End If

                        Else
0
                        End If
                        'Set target = Nothing

              '      End If

             Next cell

        End If
    'to test if not in the target specified
    'MsgBox "Not in range"
   ***Else
   Exit Sub
   End If***

 With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
 End With

Exit Sub
ermess:
MsgBox "VBA Error" & vbLf & Err.Description & vbLf & Err.Number, vbCritical

'Debug.Print

End Sub
```